# Home/Away Assist and the Nest API

Tags: nest-api

Today, Nest announced [Home/Away Assist](https://nest.com/blog/2016/03/10/introducing-family-accounts-and-home-away-assist/).

Will this be exposed in the Nest API to allow Works With Nest products to support this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home/Away Assist is an app feature that feeds the Auto-Away. It was built specifically to be compatible by default with the current API. Home and Away works the same if you're a developer, just now with more accurate information.

Comment: Understood. In the [developer terms of service](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/tos) it states that you may not _implement functionality that interferes with the core functionality of Nest products or services_. So, for example, you must not write a WWN app that controls Away state in the background. Home/Away Assist seems to do just this (based on device location). Will it now be permitted to implement similar features in a WWN app?

Comment: Automatically controlling Away state in most scenarios is still not allowed. Users must be prompted.